# Transact sql, построение запроса на обновление из двух таблиц

Tags: sql-server, update

Есть ошибка в запросе SQL

```
update #WRONGDOG as a
set a.ldap_login=b.ldap_login
from #BOOST as b
where b.eca_brnm=a.eca_brnm
and BUS_BUS=38
```

тут запрос на обновление постороен из  двух  таблиц, что **не верно**, 
помогите посторить правильно

Comment: `update a set ... from #WRONGDOG as a, #BOOST as b where ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При обновлении таблицы конструкцией `update ... from ...` не забывайте о таком факторе, как количество строк в источнике, соответствующих одной строке в целевой таблице. Возможные варианты: "один к одному" и "несколько к одному". Рассмотрим на примере.

Пусть есть таблицы

```
create table #A ([match] int, [column] int);
create table #B ([match] int, [column] int);
```

Будем обновлять `#A` данными из `#B`.

Вариант **"Один к одному"**

Добавим данных в таблицы:

```
insert into #A values (1, 10);
insert into #B values (1, 100);
```

В этом случае, как уже указал участник [gofr1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/201632/gofr1) в своём ответе, для обновления мы можем использовать запрос

```
update A
set A.[column] = B.[column]
from #A A
    join #B B on B.[match] = A.[match];
```

Вариант **"Несколько к одному"**

Добавим в таблицы ещё данных - таких, чтобы одной строке в целевой таблице соответствовало несколько строк в источнике:

```
insert into #A values (2, 20);
insert into #B values (2, 200);
insert into #B values (2, 2000);
```

Теперь, если будем для обновления использовать тот же запрос, что и в предыдущем случае, то обновление произойдёт, однако, никаких гарантий относительно того, каким из значений (200 или 2000) обновится `[column]` в `#A` с `[match] = 2` не существует.

Конструкция `merge` в этом плане более предусмотрительна. Если попытаемся с помощью `merge` проделать то же самое:

```
merge into #A A
using (select * from #B) B
on A.[match] = B.[match]
when matched then
    update
    set A.[column] = B.[column];
```

то получим ошибку Msg 8672:

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more
>   than once...

Т.е. в случае "несколько к одному" перед обновление необходимо привести данные к виду "один к одному" любым подходящим случаю образом. Например, с помощью агрегации

```
;with B ([match], [column])
as (
    select [match], max([column])
    from #B
    group by [match]
)
update A
set A.[column] = B.[column]
from #A A
    join B on B.[match] = A.[match];
```

или дополнительной фильтрации

```
;with B ([match], [column], rowNum)
as (
    select [match], [column],
         row_number() over (partition by [match] order by [column])
    from #B
)
update A
set A.[column] = B.[column]
from #A A
    join B on B.[match] = A.[match] and B.rowNum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Не надо использовать устаревший синтаксис при связывании таблиц (через запятую). Корректный запрос выглядит так:

```
UPDATE A
SET ldap_login=b.ldap_login
FROM #WRONGDOG A
INNER JOIN #BOOST b
    ON A.eca_brnm=a.eca_brnm AND bus_bus=38
```